# Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) with SDL2 and C++ class

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, valgrind

I'm using Valgrind on Debian 8.2. I ran `valgrind -v --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes --track-origins=yes --log-file=valgrind-$PROGRAM.log ./$PROGRAM` where `PROGRAM` was the name of the program.

Valgrind gave me this complaint several times:

```
==7125== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==7125==    at 0xE816EC3: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.340.96)
==7125==    by 0x4E8DB30: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.2.0)
==7125==    by 0x4E8DBCF: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.2.0)
==7125==    by 0x4E90A92: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.2.0)
==7125==    by 0x4E887BF: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.2.0)
==7125==    by 0x403ACF: Graphics::Graphics(char const*, int, int, int, unsigned int) (Graphics.cpp:25)
==7125==    by 0x401974: Game::run() (Game.cpp:62)
==7125==    by 0x403EC5: main (main.cpp:13)
==7125==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==7125==    at 0x4E8D830: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.2.0)
```

And this one:

```
==7125== 28 bytes in 2 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 19 of 125
==7125==    at 0x4C28C20: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:296)
==7125==    by 0x59DCA69: strdup (strdup.c:42)
==7125==    by 0x66C66C6: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==7125==    by 0x66C74F4: _XimSetICValueData (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==7125==    by 0x66C2A28: _XimLocalCreateIC (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==7125==    by 0x66A7E54: XCreateIC (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==7125==    by 0x4EEFB30: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.2.0)
==7125==    by 0x4EEFF45: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.2.0)
==7125==    by 0x4EE30CB: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.2.0)
==7125==    by 0x403A88: Graphics::Graphics(char const*, int, int, int, unsigned int) (Graphics.cpp:19)
==7125==    by 0x401974: Game::run() (Game.cpp:62)
==7125==    by 0x403EC5: main (main.cpp:13)
```

The lines of `main.cpp` and `Game.cpp` Valgrind refers to lead to `Graphics.cpp`.

`Graphics.h` looks like this:

```
#ifndef GRAPHICS_H
#define GRAPHICS_H

struct SDL_Window;
struct SDL_Renderer;

class Graphics {
private:
    const char      *_windowTitle;
    int             _windowWidth, _windowHeight;
    SDL_Window      *_window;
    SDL_Renderer    *_renderer;
    int             _renderingDriverIndex;
    Uint32          _rendererFlags;
public:
    Graphics(const char* windowTitle, int windowWidth, int windowHeight, int renderingDriverIndex, Uint32 renderFlags);
    ~Graphics();

    int             windowWidth();
    int             windowHeight();
    void            changeWindowSize(int width, int height);
    SDL_Renderer*   renderer(); // since _renderer is pointer, this func must return a SDL_Renderer pointer
    void            setBackgroundColor();
    void            clear();
    void            update();

};

#endif /* GRAPHICS_H */
```

The `Graphics` object constructor looks like this in `Graphics.cpp`. Valgrind seems to be complaining about the definitions of `_window` and `_renderer`:

```
Graphics::Graphics(const char* windowTitle, int windowWidth, int windowHeight, int renderingDriverIndex, Uint32 renderFlags) :
    _windowTitle            (windowTitle),
    _windowWidth            (windowWidth),
    _windowHeight           (windowHeight),
    _renderingDriverIndex   (renderingDriverIndex), // get the index of the first graphics driver available(?)
    _rendererFlags          (renderFlags)
{
    _window=                SDL_CreateWindow(_windowTitle, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, _windowWidth, _windowHeight, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);  // LINE 19
    if(_window == 0){
        printError("SDL_CreateWindow");
        SDL_Quit();
    }

    _renderer=              SDL_CreateRenderer(_window, _renderingDriverIndex, _rendererFlags); // LINE 25
    if(_renderer == NULL){
        printError("SDL_CreateRenderer");
        SDL_Quit();
    }

    if(SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(_renderer, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND) == -1){
        printError("SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode");
        SDL_Quit();
    }
}
```

Why does Valgrind complain about uninitialized variables when I define them in either `Graphic`'s member initialization list or the class's object constructor?